RealityKit: Rotate a part of a 3d model towards the camera
I have a 3D model of an object with animation embedded in it. The model also has a skeleton. I need the object displayed in AR to turn its head towards the camera. How can this be implemented programmatically?
I thought about implementing this by manipulating bones, but I found out that RealityKit (iOS 16) does not provide this option.
If I load the model as Entity, then I have a graph of objects of the Entity type - the geometry of the model, but no bones.
If I load the model as ModelEntity, then I do not have direct access to the tree of child elements at all, but there are 2 lists: jointNames and jointTransforms. As I understand it, these are lists of names and transformations of bones, respectively.
Below is the code for basic loading of the object:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit
import Combine

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        
        addCouchingOverlay(arView: arView)
        addModelToARView(arView: arView, context: context)
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ARCoordinator {
        ARCoordinator()
    }
    
    private func addModelToARView(arView: ARView, context: Context) {
        Entity.loadModelAsync(named: "model.usdz").sink(
            receiveCompletion: { completion in
                if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                    print("Error loading model: \(error)")
                }
            },
            receiveValue: { modelEntity in
                configureModel(context: context, arView: arView, modelEntity: modelEntity)
            }
        ).store(in: &context.coordinator.cancellables)
    }
}
 

extension ARViewContainer {
    private func addCouchingOverlay(arView: ARView) {
        let coachingOverlay = ARCoachingOverlayView()
        coachingOverlay.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        coachingOverlay.session = arView.session
        coachingOverlay.goal = .horizontalPlane
        arView.addSubview(coachingOverlay)
    }
    
    private func configureModel(context: Context, arView: ARView, modelEntity: ModelEntity) {
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        
        anchorEntity.addChild(modelEntity)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
        
        let minScale: Float = 0.001
        modelEntity.scale = [minScale, minScale, minScale]
        context.coordinator.modelEntity = modelEntity
        
        arView.scene.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self) { _ in
            let currentScale = modelEntity.scale.x
            if currentScale < minScale {
                modelEntity.scale = [minScale, minScale, minScale]
            }
        }.store(in: &context.coordinator.cancellables)
    }
}

class ARCoordinator {
    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    var modelEntity: ModelEntity?
}

It seems to me that the most correct way is to manipulate the bones of the skeleton of the 3D model. But in RealityKit for iOS 16, this functionality is not directly available. Or are there ways to animate the effect on bones/joints?
During the experiment, I discovered that when changing the transformations in the jointTransforms list, the model itself visually changes. Therefore, I even tried to assemble my own tree from Entity by setting names and transformations from the jointNames and jointTransforms lists. Then I store them in the coordinator object for quick access to them, as well as the indices of the necessary joints for subsequent updates of the values ​​in jointTransforms.
I run a function on a timer to change the bone transformation according to the following logic:

take the entities of the head, neck and the model itself
get the position of the head relative to the neck
perform a transformation for the head using the look(at:, from:, upVector: relativeTo:) function
overwrite the value in jointTransforms by index

Here is an example of code:
import Foundation
import RealityKit
import Combine

class ARCoordinator {
    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    var modelEntity: ModelEntity?
    var entity: Entity?
    
    var neck: Entity?
    var head: Entity?
    var lEye: Entity?
    var rEye: Entity?
    
    var headTransformIdx = 0
    var lEyeTransformIdx = 0
    var rEyeTransformIdx = 0
    
    private var trackingTimer: Timer?
    
    private var skeletoneIsBuilded = false
    private var entities: [String: Entity] = [:]
    
    func startCameraTrackingTimer(arView: ARView) {
        trackingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            if let isBuilded = self?.skeletoneIsBuilded, isBuilded {
                self?.updateModelOrientation(arView: arView)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func prepareEntities() {
        let neckName = "root/body/neck"
        let headName = "root/body/neck/head"
        let eyeLName = "root/body/neck/head/eye_left"
        let eyeRName = "root/body/neck/head/eye_right"
        
        if let entity = entities[neckName],
           let idx = modelEntity?.jointNames.firstIndex(where: { $0.hasSuffix("/neck") }) {
            neck = entity
        }
        
        if let entity = entities[headName],
           let idx = modelEntity?.jointNames.firstIndex(where: { $0.hasSuffix("/head") }) {
            head = entity
            headTransformIdx = idx
        }
        
        if let entity = entities[eyeLName],
           let idx = modelEntity?.jointNames.firstIndex(where: { $0.hasSuffix("/eye_left") }) {
            lEye = entity
            lEyeTransformIdx = idx
        }
        
        if let entity = entities[eyeRName],
           let idx = modelEntity?.jointNames.firstIndex(where: { $0.hasSuffix("/eye_right") }) {
            rEye = entity
            rEyeTransformIdx = idx
        }
    }
    
    func stopCameraTrackingTimer() {
        trackingTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    private func updateModelOrientation(arView: ARView) {
        if let modelEntity = modelEntity,
           let neck = neck,
           let head = head {
            
            let position = head.position(relativeTo: neck)
            head.look(
                at: arView.cameraTransform.translation,
                from: position,
                upVector: [0, 1, 0],
                relativeTo: neck
            )
            
            modelEntity.jointTransforms[headTransformIdx] = head.transform
        }
    }
    
    func buildGraphAsync(jointNames: [String], jointTransforms: [Transform]) async -> Entity? {
        let graphRoot: Entity? = await withTaskGroup(of: Entity?.self) { group in
            group.addTask { [weak self] in
                return self?.buildGraph(jointNames: jointNames, jointTransforms: jointTransforms)
            }
            
            return await group.first(where: { $0 != nil }) ?? nil
        }
        
        skeletoneIsBuilded = true
        prepareEntities()
        
        return graphRoot
    }
    
    private func buildGraph(jointNames: [String], jointTransforms: [Transform]) -> Entity? {
        guard jointNames.count == jointTransforms.count else {
            print("Error: the number of names and transformations does not match.")
            return nil
        }

        var idx = 0
        let root = Entity.create(name: jointNames[idx], transform: jointTransforms[idx])
        entities = [jointNames[idx]: root]
        idx += 1

        while idx < jointNames.count {
            let name = jointNames[idx]
            let transform = jointTransforms[idx]
            
            let parentPathComponents = name.split(separator: "/").dropLast()
            let parentName = parentPathComponents.joined(separator: "/")

            let entity = Entity.create(name: name, transform: transform)
            entities[name] = entity

            if let parent = entities[parentName] {
                parent.addChild(entity)
            } else {
                print("Parent not fount for: \(name)")
            }
            
            idx += 1
        }
        
        return root
    }
}

extension Entity {
    static func create(name: String, transform: Transform) -> Entity {
        let entity = Entity()
        entity.name = name
        entity.transform = transform
        
        return entity
    }
}


struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        // ...
        
        context.coordinator.startCameraTrackingTimer(arView: arView)
        
        return arView
    }
    
    private func configureModel(context: Context, arView: ARView, modelEntity: ModelEntity) {
        // ...
        
        Task.detached {
            let entity = await context.coordinator.buildGraphAsync(
                jointNames: modelEntity.jointNames,
                jointTransforms: modelEntity.jointTransforms
            )
            
            await MainActor.run {
                context.coordinator.entity = entity
            }
        }
    }
}

I experimented with different options for calling the look(at:, from:, upVector: relativeTo:) function:

changed values ​​in upVector
set the neck object and nil as relativeTo

I currently have the following problems with this approach:

if you select the vector correctly, the head rotates, but only horizontally. There is no movement along the vertical axis.
I noticed that the model's head abruptly changes direction in the opposite direction even before the camera is on the other side. That is, it seems as if the point from which the direction towards the camera is calculated is noticeably closer to the observer than the object itself. that is, this point is between the object and the camera. Perhaps it is necessary to somehow set the binding correctly...

Can someone help with solving this problem? First of all, I am interested in the correct solution for implementing the direction of the model's head towards the camera
Thank you in advance for any help)
